# C++11 class lattice with mixed virtual and non-virtual bases?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 (N3485) 10.1.4 [class.mi] it says:

> For each distinct occurence of a *non-virtual* base class in the class lattice of the most derived class, the most derived object shall contain a corresponding *distinct* base class subobject of that type.
>
> For each distinct base class that is specified *virtual*, the most derived class shall contain a *single* base class object of that type.

Consider the following C++11 code:

```
struct B {};

struct BV : virtual B {};
struct BN : B {};

struct C1 : BV, BN {};
struct C2 : BV, BN {};

struct D : C1, C2 {};
```

Firstly, for clarity, how many vertices does the class lattice of D have?

Secondly, how many distinct subobjects of type B does the standard require that a most derived object of type D have?

**update:**

Which of the following is the class lattice?

(1)

```
    B     B     B    B
    ^     ^     ^    ^
    |     |     |    |
    BV    BN    BV   BN
    ^     ^     ^    ^
    |     |     |    |
     \   /       \  /
       C1         C2
         \        /
          \      /
           -  D -
```

(2)

```
    B<---------
    ^          \
    |           |
    |     B     |    B
    |     ^     |    ^
    |     |     |    |
    BV    BN    BV   BN
    ^     ^     ^    ^
    |     |     |    |
     \   /       \  /
       C1         C2
         \        /
          \      /
           -  D -
```

(3)

```
       B   
      /  \     
     /    \ 
    BV    BN
    | \  / |
    |  \/  |
    |  / \ |
    | /   \|
    C1     C2
     \    /
      \  /
       D
```

If the intention is that it is (1) then isn't it impossible to have any DAG that isn't a tree? (ie a diamond is impossible)  If so wouldn't it be better to call it the class tree?

If it is (2) wouldn't it be sufficient to say "for each occurence of a base class in the class lattice there is a corresponding base class subobject" ?.  That is, if the construction of the lattice already depends on virtual and non-virtual base class relationships to select edges and vertices?

If it is (3) then isn't the language incorrect in the standard because there can only ever be one occurence of a class in the class lattice?

Comment: 1. there are 10 vertices 2. there are 2 non-virtual B's and 1 virtual B

Comment: @fatih_k: How did you arrive at 10?

Comment: from D to C's there are 2 vertices, C1 to B's 2, C2 to B's 2,  there are 2 BV' and 1 vertex to virtual B, and 2 vertices from BN to B : total 9 sorry.

Comment: @faith_k: Are you conflating edges and vertices possibly?

Comment: yes, I wrongly recalled them as node-vertex pairs but node and vertex are equivalent.  Then there are 9 edges and 10 nodes(vertices) including class D

Comment: @faith_k: Perhaps your claim would be clearer if you listed the names of each of the 10 vertices.

Comment: yes it is the graph with number 2

Comment: @faith_k: How do you know it is number 2?

Comment: Note the Standard does not define what a *class lattice* is (the term is used, though), but it defines and depicts *subobject lattices*, [class.derived]/5 "A DAG of subobjects is often referred to as a “subobject lattice.”"

Comment: @user1131467, from the reference you gave ofcourse

Comment: @DyP: How did you conclude there is 1 BV, isn't the subobject lattice (2) and there are 2 BV (D::C1::BV and D::C2::BV)

Comment: Oh! I misread the code. You're right, (2) is the subobject lattice.

Answer (score 3):

> Which of the following is the class lattice?

2

Demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {};

struct BV : virtual B {};
struct BN : B {};

struct C1 : BV, BN {};
struct C2 : BV, BN {};

struct D : C1, C2 {};

int
main()
{
    D d;
    C1* c1 = static_cast<C1*>(&d);
    BV* bv1 = static_cast<BV*>(c1);
    BN* bn1 = static_cast<BN*>(c1);
    B* b1 = static_cast<B*>(bv1);
    B* b2 = static_cast<B*>(bn1);
    C2* c2 = static_cast<C2*>(&d);
    BV* bv2 = static_cast<BV*>(c2);
    BN* bn2 = static_cast<BN*>(c2);
    B* b3 = static_cast<B*>(bv2);
    B* b4 = static_cast<B*>(bn2);
    std::cout << "d = " << &d << '\n';
    std::cout << "c1 = " << c1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "c2 = " << c2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "bv1 = " << bv1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "bv2 = " << bv2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "bn1 = " << bn1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "bn2 = " << bn2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "b1 = " << b1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "b2 = " << b2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "b3 = " << b3 << '\n';
    std::cout << "b4 = " << b4 << '\n';
}
```

My output:

```
d = 0x7fff5ca18998
c1 = 0x7fff5ca18998
c2 = 0x7fff5ca189a0
bv1 = 0x7fff5ca18998
bv2 = 0x7fff5ca189a0
bn1 = 0x7fff5ca18998
bn2 = 0x7fff5ca189a0
b1 = 0x7fff5ca189a8
b2 = 0x7fff5ca18998
b3 = 0x7fff5ca189a8
b4 = 0x7fff5ca189a0
```

> If it is (2) wouldn't it be sufficient to say "for each occurence of a
>   base class in the class lattice there is a corresponding base class
>   subobject" ?. That is, if the construction of the lattice already
>   depends on virtual and non-virtual base class relationships to select
>   edges and vertices?

Merging your suggestion...

> A base class specifier that contains the keyword **virtual**,
>   specifies a *virtual* base class. For each <del>distinct</del>
>   occurrence of a <del>non-virtual</del> base class in the class lattice
>   <del>of the most derived class, the most derived object (1.8) shall
>   contain</del> there is a corresponding <del>distinct</del>
>   base class subobject <del>of that type</del>.  <del>For each distinct
>   base class that is specified virtual, the most derived object shall
>   contain a single base class subobject of that type.</del>

I'm not an expert in the language half of the standard.  However when I read your modified specification, I don't see how:

```
class V { /∗...∗/ };
class A : virtual public V { /∗ ... ∗/ };
class B : virtual public V { /∗ ... ∗/ };
class C : public A, public B { /∗...∗/ };
```

Results in Figure 4:

```
   V
  / \
 /   \
A     B
 \   /
  \ /
   C
```

I don't see another place in the standard that specifies that although `V` appears twice in the class hierarchy below `C`, only one subobject of type `V` actually exists because of the use of the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: I agree that (2) is the _subobject_ lattice, but I don't think the standard has clearly specified if the _class_ lattice is (1) or (2)

Comment: @user1131467 Could you clarify the terms `subobject lattice` and `class lattice`? I've never heard the term lattice used in this context before and I can't understand your comment.

Comment: @MarkB: Well the precise definition is what we are trying to clarify.  The terms are both used in section 10.1 of the C++ standard, but their definition is a little vague.

Comment: If there were a precise meaning of the term "class lattice" intended, such a definition would appear in 1.3 [intro.defs].  The term "class lattice" has no precise definition is used in the spirit of having a "commonly understood"  definition.  In your example, all class `B`s have the same type.  So in that sense, (3) might be a better diagram for you.  That part is assumed to be understood and [class.mi] is just trying to explain how many subobjects of each type are laid out in memory, and how each subobject can be related to other subobjects via static_cast and dynamic_cast.